# How should I make database relationships

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to make an application that teaches English words, sentences and phrases. Can you help me how to design the database of this application?

Notes:

- I use C# and SQL Server
- Windows Forms

I can't upload them all here, so I'll leave the link

https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/158X_TwNhbrCc6d_zldutBd8D0-VwxtgC

```
CREATE TABLE tblTurkishWords 
(
    WordID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    TurkishWords nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE tblEnglishWords   
(
    WordsID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    EnglishWords nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE tblDescriptions 
(
    DescriptionID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    EnglishWordDescription nchar(100) NOT NULL,
    EnglishSentenceDescription nchar(100) NOT NULL,
    EnglishPhraseDescription nchar(100) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE tblPhonetic 
(
    PhoneticID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    EnglishWordPhonetic nchar(100) NOT NULL,
    EnglishSentencePhonetic nchar(100) NOT NULL,
    EnglishPhrasePhonetic nchar(100) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE tblMedia 
(
    MediaID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    EnglishWordMedia nchar(100) NOT NULL,
    EnglishSentenceMedia nchar(100) NOT NULL,
    EnglishPhraseMedia nchar(100) NOT NULL,
);

--there will be pictures related to the relevant words in the media section
CREATE TABLE tblYouTubeLink 
(
    LinkID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    EnglishWordLink nchar(100) NOT NULL,
    EnglishSentenceLink nchar(100) NOT NULL,
    EnglishPhraseLink nchar(100) NOT NULL,
);

--here will be film scenes from youtube to illustrate the words
CREATE TABLE tblReadingAudioFiles 
(
    AudioFileID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    EnglishWordAudioFile nchar(100) NOT NULL,
    EnglishSentenceAudioFile nchar(100) NOT NULL,
    EnglishPhraseAudioFile nchar(100) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE tblKnown? 
(
    KnownID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    EnglishWordKnown bit NOT NULL,
    EnglishSentenceKnown bit NOT NULL,
    EnglishPhraseKnown bit NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE tblWrong 
(
    WrongID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    EnglishWordWrong INT NOT NULL,
    EnglishSentenceWrong INT NOT NULL,
    EnglishPhraseWrong INT NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE tblCorrect 
(
    CorrectID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    EnglishWordCorrect INT NOT NULL,
    EnglishSentenceCorrect INT NOT NULL,
    EnglishPhraseCorrect INT NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE tblTurkishFamousWord 
(
    WordID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    TurkishWord nchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tblEnglishFamousWord 
(
    WordID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    EnglishWord nchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tblTurkishSentence 
(
    SentenceID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    TurkishSentence nchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tblEnglishSentence 
(
    SentenceID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    EnglishSentence nchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tblTurkishPhrase 
(
    PhraseID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    TurkishPhrase nchar(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE tblEnglishPhrase 
(
    PhraseID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    EnglishPhrase nchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

I tried to prepare a database as I gave in the example, but I didn't get much idea about how to make their relationship

Comment: ALTER TABLE Orders ADD FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID), chnage it to your structure

Comment: There is no reason to use prefixes like `tbl`, in fact it's an anti-pattern that will cause problems in future.

Comment: Why do word, sentence, and phrase have different fields in all those tables?  Aren't they all essentially the same thing?  What are "known", "wrong", and "correct"?  Couldn't you use one table that has a "status" field?

Comment: @Dai In our organisation we also use these prefixes, but can you explain how this can cause problems in the future ?

Comment: @GuidoG https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/is-adding-the-tbl-prefix-to-table-names-really-a-problem